# Is there any way to tell that a Care Package is booby-trapped?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

In Black Ops 2, the ability to booby trap a care package is available with Hacker Pro.  Is there any visual clue or other way to tell that a care package has been booby trapped, if you're on the other team?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the `Engineer` perk it will be highlighted in red with red shading making it very obvious. Failing that, its usually fairly obvious if no-one on the opposite team is trying to get the care package.

Also the lottery of what is in the care package is reset. Meaning that it may change from a UAV to a Sentry Gun.